# ACF shortcode for inline css using content editor in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system, advanced-custom-fields

So this seems to not work on wordpress, any reason why this might be happening, I am using Advanced Custom Fields plugin and every custom field shortcode I have used in my content editor which is executed using `the_content();` is working perfectly fine. even shortcodes in `<a href="">` tags.

But for some reason this one gets ignored, if I take it out of the `style=""` and test it, I get the image URL value, but in the `background-image:` attribute I get no value.

```
<header class="docs-main" style="background-image: url('[acf field='header-background-image']');">

</header>
```

Comment: Is your background image set to URL only?

Comment: Yep sure is. That's alright I did a alternative method and styled it in my header with style tags and echo out the php field in the header and it worked. Not sure why it did not work in the content Editor though

Comment: I have no idea why you are trying to do this. What is the advantage comparing to use a shortcode for the whole expression including the html?